# Parallel processing in python using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I have a program that is supposed to be a web crawler that processes and traverses  URLs from separate pages concurrently. When the array of URLs gets too full, the program splits the array into four quarters and recursively computes them using threading. This program is designed to continue this mechanism until all of the pages on a web site have been traversed, as indicated by the maximum size of the visited array (10,000). The problem I am having is that for some reason, the program is only running the last thread of the recursive sequence. Here is the portion of my code I am having problems with:

```
def WebScraper(urls, threadID):
global visited

while len(urls) > 0 and len(visited) <= 10000:
    try:
        htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    except:
        print urls[0]

    url = urls[0]
    urls.pop(0)
    print "Thread #" + str(threadID) + " - " + str(len(urls)) + "\n"

    if len(urls) >= 150:

        print "Number visited " + str(len(visited)) + "\n"

        queueLock = threading.Lock()
        workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
        threads = []
        thread = ""

        newThread1 = myThread(urls[:len(urls)/4])
        newThread1.start()
        threads.append(newThread1)

        newThread2 = myThread(urls[len(urls)/4:len(urls)/2])
        newThread2.start()
        threads.append(newThread2)

        newThread3 = myThread(urls[len(urls)/2:3 * len(urls)/4])
        newThread3.start()
        threads.append(newThread3)

        newThread4 = myThread(urls[3 * len(urls)/4:])
        newThread4.start()
        threads.append(newThread4)

        queueLock.acquire()

        for thread in threads:
            workQueue.put(thread)

        while not workQueue.empty():
            pass

        for t in threads:
            t.join()

        break

    else:
        for tags in soup.findAll("a",href=True):
            tags["href"] = urlparse.urljoin(url, tags["href"])
            #print tags["href"]
            if url in tags["href"] and tags["href"] not in visited:
                TotalUrls.append(tags["href"])
                urls.append(tags["href"])
                visited.append(tags["href"])
```

This is the result I am getting:

Thread #0 - 0

Thread #0 - 153

Number visited 154

Thread #:1
Thread #:2
Thread #:3
Thread #:4

Thread #4 - 37

Thread #4 - 37

Thread #4 - 38

Thread #4 - 37

Thread #4 - 36

Thread #4 - 36

Thread #4 - 37

Thread #4 - 37

Thread #4 - 48

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://scrapy.org/ if you just need a crawler, it has solved all of these problems and is amazingly scalable with plugins for distributed scraping from multiple machines

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Scrapy for some reason, the following code will give you a head start.

In general, multithreaded programs are *much* easier using the `multiprocessing.Pool()` facility. You create a pool, send it a huge list of jobs, it gives you each result as it comes.

This doesn't work gracefully for scraping-type problems, where we don't have a fixed-size list of input jobs at the beginning.  For this class of problem I've developed the following solution.

- start threads, giving each an input queue and other args
- each thread does some work, then adds more jobs (URLs) to the *same* input queue that all the threads are using
- one thread won't just zoom through all the URLs
- when a thread can't find a new job in 5 seconds, it'll die

The above techniques leads to a simple but powerful multi-threaded queue solution.

Have fun!

### source

```
#!/bin/env python

import multiprocessing, threading, time, urllib, urlparse
import logging, os, Queue, sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)-4s %(levelname)s %(threadName)s %(message)s", 
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stderr,
)

def scan_page(url, soup):
    """return link URLs from HTML page"""
    for tags in soup.findAll("a",href=True):
        yield urlparse.urljoin(url, tags["href"])

def scan_url(url):
    """fetch page, return URLs, print timing"""
    start = time.time()
    page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    res = list( scan_page(url, BeautifulSoup(page)) )
    logging.debug(
        '- %s: %.2f, %d links', 
        url, time.time()-start, len(res)
    )
    return res

def scan_queue(inqueue, visited):
    logging.info('start')
    while True:
        try:
            url = inqueue.get(timeout=5)
            if len(visited) > 10:
                logging.info('exiting, visited 10 URLs')
                break                
            if url in visited:
                logging.info('%s: ignoring visited URL', url)
                continue
            logging.info('url: %s', url)
            visited.add( url )
        except Queue.Empty:
            break
        links = scan_url(url)
        for link in set(links) - visited:
            inqueue.put( link )
    logging.info('done')

def master(root):
    # native Python objects are thread-safe
    # TODO: quote manual
    visited = set()

    url_queue = Queue.Queue() # pylint: disable=E1101
    url_queue.put(root)

    threads = [
        threading.Thread(
            target=scan_queue, args=[
                url_queue, visited,
                ],
        )
        for _ in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    ]

    for th in threads:
        th.start()
    for th in threads:
        th.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master('http://example.com')
```

### output

```
13:26:57 INFO Thread-1 start
13:26:57 INFO Thread-1 url: http://example.com
13:26:57 INFO Thread-2 start
13:26:57 INFO Thread-3 start
13:26:57 INFO Thread-4 start
13:26:57 DEBUG Thread-1 - http://example.com: 0.12, 1 links
13:26:57 INFO Thread-1 url: http://www.iana.org/domains/example
13:26:58 DEBUG Thread-1 - http://www.iana.org/domains/example: 0.62, 64 links
13:26:58 INFO Thread-2 url: http://www.iana.org/contact
13:26:58 INFO Thread-1 url: http://www.iana.org/time-zones
13:26:58 INFO Thread-4 url: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/xn--kgbechtv.html
13:26:58 INFO Thread-3 url: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/xn--0zwm56d.html
13:26:58 DEBUG Thread-2 - http://www.iana.org/contact: 0.23, 34 links
13:26:58 INFO Thread-2 url: http://www.iana.org/domains/int/manage
13:26:58 DEBUG Thread-1 - http://www.iana.org/time-zones: 0.30, 39 links
13:26:58 INFO Thread-1 url: http://www.iana.org/go/rfc2606
13:26:58 DEBUG Thread-4 - http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/xn--kgbechtv.html: 0.33, 49 links
13:26:58 INFO Thread-4 url: http://www.iana.org/numbers
13:26:59 DEBUG Thread-2 - http://www.iana.org/domains/int/manage: 0.23, 51 links
13:26:59 INFO Thread-2 url: http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa
13:26:59 DEBUG Thread-4 - http://www.iana.org/numbers: 0.21, 62 links
13:26:59 INFO Thread-4 url: http://www.icann.org/en/registries/agreements.htm
13:26:59 DEBUG Thread-2 - http://www.iana.org/domains/arpa: 0.19, 59 links
13:26:59 INFO Thread-2 exiting, visited 10 URLs
13:26:59 INFO Thread-2 done
13:26:59 DEBUG Thread-1 - http://www.iana.org/go/rfc2606: 0.42, 37 links
13:26:59 INFO Thread-1 exiting, visited 10 URLs
13:26:59 INFO Thread-1 done
13:26:59 DEBUG Thread-3 - http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/xn--0zwm56d.html: 0.75, 49 links
13:26:59 INFO Thread-3 exiting, visited 10 URLs
13:26:59 INFO Thread-3 done
13:27:01 DEBUG Thread-4 - http://www.icann.org/en/registries/agreements.htm: 2.83, 1098 links
13:27:01 INFO Thread-4 exiting, visited 10 URLs
13:27:01 INFO Thread-4 done
```